# Can't get toggleClass to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been trying to get this simple code to work for hours but need help as it does not seem to work.

I'm using toggleClass in a js file to switch class on the header. I´ve tried every possible way, also tried it in jsfiddle and it works sometimes and sometimes not even with the same code. So something is definitely wrong.

Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html> 
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Menu</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menystyle.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="large">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Posts</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <section class="stretch">
            <p>Make menu small</p>
            <p>End of the line.</p>
        </section>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="menu.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the script code in the js file:

```
$(document).on("scroll", function () {
    $("header").toggleClass("small", $(document).scrollTop() > 100);
});
```

And here is the CSS:

```
body{ background-color: #ebebeb; }
ul{ float: right; }
li{ display: inline; float: left;} img.logo{float: left;}
/* Size and center the menu */ nav{ width: 960px; margin: 0 auto;} 

section.stretch{ float: left; height: 1500px; width: 100%; }
section.stretch p{ font-family: 'Amaranth', sans-serif; font-size: 30px; color: #969696; text-align: center; position: relative; margin-top: 250px; }
section.stretch p.bottom{ top: 100%; } 

header{ background: #C7C7C7; border-bottom: 1px solid #aaaaaa; float: left; width: 100%; position: fixed; z-index: 10; }
header a{ color: #969696; text-decoration: none; font-family: 'Amaranth', sans-serif; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 1em; }
header a.active, header a:hover{ color: #3d3d3d; }
header li{ margin-right: 30px; }

/* Sizes for the bigger menu */
header.large{ height: 120px; }
header.large img{ width: 489px; height: 113px; }
header.large li{ margin-top: 45px; }

/* Sizes for the smaller menu */
header.small{ height: 50px; }
header.small img{ width: 287px; height: 69px; margin-top: -10px; }
header.small li{ margin-top: 17px; }
```

Comment: It works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/kPRaK/

Comment: The problem is that the header doesn´t change. It remains the same.

Comment: Hi Joe, I tried it on jsfiddle and it works sometimes and sometimes not. Even when I´m trying the exact same code. And when I try i the browser it never works. The header remains the same... @Joe

Comment: It's working consistently for me in multiple browsers. Which browser are you using?

Comment: I´ve tried all major browsers:(

Comment: Ok, but are you even including the jquery library? Add `<script src="http//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` before you include `menu.js`.

Comment: No but I just did and it still does not work:( I pasted that same script link in the head of the html document. Then added the script link underneath to the menu.js file @Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the head tags, include this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

It should work after that.

Comment: Finally!!! It works!!! What is the difference on all those jquery links? Thank you! @Elmer

Comment: In order to use jQuery, you have to include the library. So you have to include it in the `<head>`. All the links shown above are the same. I dont think you put it in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Include [jquery.min.js](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js) in your code and then your code will work fine. [See your code in working condition](http://jsbin.com/UTorAYA/1/edit).

Comment: Hi Sanjeev, Thanks for your reply! Where exactly should I add this? In the file name?

Comment: Hi Karolina, as u can see that this is a javascript file. So, u have to add this file using script tag. For more help see the above mentioned link ("See your code in working condition").